# Excepciones en Java

Tags: java, poo, excepciones

Quisiera saber como crear mi propia excepción para controlar que las notas solo tengan el rango de 1 a 10, que si no se cumple salte un mensaje

Código:

```
System.out.println("Introduca fecha de nacimiento");
            do{             
                System.out.print("Dia(1-31): ");
                objFecha.setDia(tecla.nextInt());                               
                System.out.print("Mes(1-12): ");
                objFecha.setMes(tecla.nextInt());
                System.out.print("Año(1980-1999): ");
                objFecha.setAnio(tecla.nextInt());
                if(objFecha.fechaCorrecta()==false)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nFecha de nacimento incorrecta, introduzca de nuevo");
                }
            }while(objFecha.fechaCorrecta()==false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, dado que en ese código no haces nada con las notas, no te puedo ayudar mucho. No obstante, te explico cómo crear una excepción con un mensaje para tu caso:

Lo primero es saber cuándo quieres que esta excepción se lance (notas en el rango [1,10] y el mensaje que envíe.

```
public void asignarNota(int nota)
{
    //lanzamos la excepción
    if(nota < 1 || nota > 10)
    {
        throw new Exception(“Error nota fuera del rango”);
    }
    else
    {
      this.nota = nota;
    }
}
```

Para capturarla sería con un simple try catch:

```
try
{
   asignarNota(10);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Más información sobre la clase Exception [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html).

Comment: Me a servido mucho de ayuda, y perdón por mi código copie lo que no era, ya que tenia una parte para las notas, no se porque copie eso

Answer (score 1):

Esto ha sido tratado en otros temas, por ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776327/how-to-define-custom-exception-class-in-java-the-easiest-way

En concreto, en tu caso deberías definir `NumeroFueraRangoException` y llamarla dentro de la clase a la que pertece `objFecha` dentro de los metodos `setDia ()`, `setMes()` y `setAnio ()` con codigo de este estilo:

```
public void setDia (int dia) throws NumeroFueraRangoException {
    If (dia > 31 || dia < 1) throw new NumeroFueraRangoException ();
    /* Resto de logica */

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado